# Can I quickly close 100s of tabs in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, tabs

It turns out one of the users of the family PC (who shall rename nameless) has a habit of double-clicking on an email message to view it, but never closes the tab.

There are now 1000s of tabs in Thunderbird (3.1.9 on Windows).  Is there a quick way to close them all?  Is there a plain-text file (XML format ok) that I can edit to get rid of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on one of the tabs and select `close other tabs`.

I've never had that many tabs, but I see no reason it would choke simple because there were that many.